# Linq to Entities-- Havine a Guid in the where clause throws error

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code

```
var bms = from b in context.bookmark
                     join q in context.question1Set on b.bookmark_id equals q.question_id
                     join u in context.userinfo on b.bookmark_ownerid equals u.user_userid
                     where b.bookmark_ownerid == new Guid(userid.ToString()) && q.question_isdeleted == false //i think it dosent't like the new Guid
                     select new
                     {
                         u.user_username,
                         q.question_title
                     };

        foreach (var bm in bms)
        {
            question q = new question();
            q.Username = bm.user_username;
            q.Title = bm.user_username;
            ql.Add(q);
        }
```

The error I get is:
**Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities**

I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Error message is pretty obvious. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Construct the Guid *before* you do the query:

```
Guid userGuid = new Guid(userid.ToString()); // What type is userid anyway?

var bms = 
     from b in context.bookmark
     join q in context.question1Set on b.bookmark_id equals q.question_id
     join u in context.userinfo on b.bookmark_ownerid equals u.user_userid
     where b.bookmark_ownerid == userGuid && !q.question_isdeleted
     select new
     {
         u.user_username,
         q.question_title
     };
```